# C++ Warning Issue

Tags: c++

> WARNING: Implicit conversion loses integer precision:
>   'std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to
>   'int32' (aka 'int')

```
// loop through all letters in the guess
int32 HiddenWordLength = MyHiddenWord.length();
for (int32 i = 0; i < HiddenWordLength; i++) {
    // compare letters against the hidden word
    for (int32 j = 0; j < HiddenWordLength; j++) {
        // if they match then
        if (Guess[i] == MyHiddenWord[i]) {
            if (i == j) { // if they're in the same place
                BullCowCount.Bulls++; // incriment bulls
            }
            else {
                BullCowCount.Cows++; // must be a cow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this one?

Comment: try to use an `std::size_t` instead of a `int32`

Comment: Your compiler error claims that you're having a type conversion error from an unsigned to an int32. Off first glance it looks like it's coming from int32 HiddenWordLength = MyHiddenWord.length();. probably because length is unsigned.

Comment: In C++ all sizes are generally an `std::size_t`, which is usually *`unsigned long`*, which is different from a (`signed`) `int`.

Comment: If on C++11 or later use `auto`

Comment: @P0W: Unless you're using a range for, personally I dislike `auto` as a `for` loop index, just in case the signed-ness changes: a compiler obviously cannot of thatl using an explicit type just might help you.

Comment: This *looks* like it should be looping over `[0, MyHiddenWord.length())` and `[0, Guess.length())`, not `MyHiddenWord.length()` twice. The comparison also makes more sense as `Guess[j] == MyHiddenWord[i]`. Note also that you will record the square of the match count for repeated letters

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't remember exactly which item, but I think Scott Meyers suggested to use `auto` citing a _similar_ example which OP has

Comment: @P0W: If he does for an explicit loop counter then I am somewhat dismayed by that; if the loop counter runs backwards then such advice is reprehensible.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think he mentioned for `size()` and `length()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string::length()` returns a `std::size_t` type.

At the time of writing, on desktop systems, that will most likely be a 64 bit `unsigned` type, whereas an `int32` is probably (if it's not a misnomer) a 32 bit `signed` type.

Your helpful compiler is warning you of this potential lossy conversion.

Consider using a `std::size_t` rather than `int32`, but do note that using an `unsigned` types in a `for` loop can cause issues if you run the counter backwards for example. In your particular case though you'll be fine.

Comment: `auto` probably also would have worked and keeps your code compiling in a couple of years when `size_t` turns into a 128-bits integer.

Comment: @CompuChip no need, it will continue being `std::size_t`

Comment: @Caleth yeah thought about that after posting. Still not a bad idea to use `auto`, just not for that reason :)